# Error Installing Ettercap-gtk

Tags: installation, apt

I'm trying to reinstall ettercap-gtk after I removed it, since it was randomly closing out for some reason, and this is the error I get

```
# apt-get install ettercap-gtk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ettercap-gtk
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B/838kB of archives.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 277050 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking ettercap-gtk (from .../ettercap-gtk_0.7.3-bt0_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/ettercap-gtk_0.7.3-bt0_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/etterlog', which is also in package ettercap-common 1:0.7.3-1.4ubuntu1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ettercap-gtk_0.7.3-bt0_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`
```

thanks for any help, I am still pretty new to linux so I'm confused by this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be mixing packages from the Ubuntu archive with those from some external source (0.7.3-bt0 does not look like a version number used by the package in Ubuntu).  In particular, the non-distro package for `ettercap-gtk` appears to contain files that have been split out into a separate `ettercap-common` package in Ubuntu.

Perhaps try disabling the additional package sources, run `apt-get update` and then try again?